# What are the data type and the data value the variable returnValue contain?

Tags: javascript

Given the following JavaScript code fragment:

```js
var x = 1;
var y = "2";
var returnValue = x + y;
```

What are the data type and the data value the variable returnValue contain?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: use `typeof` keyword to check yourself

Answer (score 2):

When you add a integer and string in JavaScript it is implicitly converted to string data type. And to check this type of the result you can use `typeof`. The `typeof` operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

**x+y**

```js
var x = 1;
var y = "2";
var returnValue = x + y;
console.log(returnValue);
console.log(typeof returnValue);
```

**y+x**

Thus, in the operation between integer and string their is no addition for `x+y` and furthermore `x+y` is not equal to the result of `y+x` due to concatenation operation

```js
var x = 1;
var y = "2";
var returnValue = y + x;
console.log(returnValue);
console.log(typeof returnValue);
```